# Maximizing the trace of the resolvent of a Wishart matrix over positive unit trace matrices?

Tags: probability-distributions, inequalities, operator-theory, random-matrices

Let $G$ be a standard $d \times d$ Wishart random matrix and consider the problem of maximizing the function
$$
f(M) = \mathbb{E}\Big[\mathrm{tr}((G + M^{-1})^{-1})\Big], 
$$
over the class of real symmetric positive definite $M$ that have unit trace.
It is possible to show that this is maximized with the choice $M = (1/d) I_d$ where $d$ denotes the dimension. (This follows by noting that the map $M \mapsto (G + M^{-1})^{-1}$ is operator concave.)

My question is how this generalizes to the following problem. Let $P$ denote a positive definite matrix and consider
$$
f_P(M) = \mathbb{E}\Big[\mathrm{tr}((G + P M^{-1}P)^{-1})\Big]. 
$$
Is it possible to determine $M^\star_P$ such that
$$
f_P(M^\star_P) = \sup_{M \succ 0, \mathrm{tr}(M) = 1} f_P(M)?
$$
The previous case reduces to $M^\star_{I_d} = \tfrac{1}{d} I_d$. A possible conjecture is that something like
$$
M^\star_P = \tfrac{1}{\mathrm{tr}(P^{-2})} P^{-2}
$$
holds, but I am unable to prove it.